# Debounce input to http service call

Tags: html, angular, typescript

What I am currently doing is set the input 2-way-binding to `appRequestParams.appName`, and on every keyup event, the `fetchApps()` method will be called.

I am trying to debounce the input such that it will not fire off a backend http request on every keyup immediately.

I have read up on ways to go about doing it and here what I have come out with.

**HTML**

```
<input #searchBox id="search" mdInput placeholder="Search by list of apps" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
```

**Typescript**

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

search(value: string): void {
       this.searchTerms.next(value);
   }


fetchApps() {
       this.appService.query({
           appName: this.appRequestParams.appName ? this.appRequestParams.appName : null,
       }).subscribe(
           (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onSuccess(res.json, res.headers),
           (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
       );
   }


ngOnInit() {
       this.searchTerms
       .debounceTime(300)
       .distinctUntilChanged()
       .switchMap((value: string) => {
           this.appRequestParams.appName = value;
           this.fetchApps();
       });
   }
```

Error on line of `.switchMap()`:

```
Argument of type '(value: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

Comment: the issue is with return type. please check the return type of your service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debounce related section of your code is fine. The problem is that you cant call switchMap withouth returning another observable.

SwitchMap basically transforms the last emitted value of an Observable into another Observable, giving the extra ability of autocanceling on the fly http requests.

Try the following:

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

search(value: string): void {
       this.searchTerms.next(value);
   }


fetchApps() {
       this.appService.query({
           appName: this.appRequestParams.appName ? this.appRequestParams.appName : null,
       });
   }


ngOnInit() {
       this.searchTerms
       .debounceTime(300)
       .distinctUntilChanged()
       .switchMap((value: string) => {
           this.appRequestParams.appName = value;
           return this.fetchApps();
       }).subscribe(
           (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onSuccess(res.json, res.headers),
           (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
       );
   }
```

A typical example is associated to the route parameters in ActivatedRoute. Consider the following:

```
  @Injectable()
  export class FooService{
    ..
    getFooById(id:string): Observable<FooInterface>{
        return this.http.get('endpoint/${id}')
         .map(res=>res.json())
         .catch(_throw(error));
    }
  }
```

Now we navigate to something like root/foo/10980312 , where the last part is defined as `:id` in the routing

```
@Component({...})
class FooPreviewComponent{
  data: FooInterface;
  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _service: FooService) {
     this._route.params
        .switchMap(params=>
          this._service.getFooById(params.id))//switchMap return type is Observable<FooInterface> because of the definition of getFooById
        .subscribe(fooElement => this.data); //intellisense will detect the type of fooElement as FooInterface because of the return type of switchmap
  }
}
```

During the time that the http is being processed, if we now navigate to root/foo/1312313, the previous request will be automatically canceled.

There are other applications for switchMap, but it requires some understanding of the internal/external observables an some internals of it.

Your solution is inefficient, because you are subscribing to the debounced input values and the http responses triggered by them, but you are doing nothing with the first, when you really just want to subscribe to the http responses. So you can save one of those subscriptions by using switchMap in the right way.

Comment: Perfect. Minor change needed under the `fetchApps()` method. Need to `return this.appService.query`

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using this and it works perfectly.

```
   this.searchTerms
   .debounceTime(300)
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .switchMap(
    (term) => {
        console.log('Term:' + term);
        this.appRequestParams.appName = term;
        this.fetchApps();
        return term;
    })
    .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Not really a smart solution in my opinion

Comment: @Jota.Toledo It was a quick fix. I am trying to understand how `switchMap` and `observables` work now. Your answer was yielding the same error hence this fix. Maybe you can shed some light on why this is not ideal?

Comment: So while this solution did solve the `it will not fire off a backend http request on every keyup immediately` issue, it does not ensure that the request response came back in order by canceling previous 'in-flight' request?